# Align vertices with another vertex, but vertices must stay on their edges

Tags: modeling

I want to align vertices along the z-axis to be in line with another vertex.  I know about S-Z-0 and pivoting around the active point, which aligns the vertices but deforms the edges these vertices are currently on.  Like when pressing GG, the vertices slide along their edges, but I also want to align them to be at the same Z position as some other vertex.

[image]

[image]

The first image is the object, and the second is the side view.  I want to align the highlighted vertices with the row below (same Z value), but I want the selected vertices to slide along their edges.

I could align the vertices by sight using GG, but is there a more precise way of snapping the vertices into place?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple way. You can move the vertices on the z-axis and use snapping to align them to the other verts, unfortunately snapping does not work while using edge slide.

To get the result you are after -

- Select the four corners of the part you want to align to
- Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> which will duplicate the vertices and leave them in the same location.
- Press <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face from these vertices
- Scale <kbd>S</kbd> this face so that it is larger than the outer edges
- Choose *Mesh->Faces->Intersect (Boolean)*
- Now select your top vertices and edge slide <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, you can move them right down - against the new vertices that are cut in the edges in line with the inner section.
- Now select all <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>w</kbd>->remove doubles,
- Select and delete the extra bits left behind. I got an extra 2 faces under the section that is now flat, I deleted the two extra edges and dissolved the two vertices to end up with the desired mesh.

[image: example editing]

Comment: Hi, thanks for response - I was experimenting with this and also decided to use the boolean intersect method, however, I used the entire outer edge of the part that I wanted to align to and basically did what you suggested, but I ended up with lots of extra edges... I think your way leaves far less carnage behind.

Comment: There is an intersect boolean and intersect knife, the knife version leaves the original outer vertices as well as another face under the centre piece, that's why I chose the boolean version.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary use a mirror modifier :

- place the 3D cursor on some point of the "row below" (select a vertice, shift+S and cursor to selected)
- in edit mode set the object's center to the 3D cursor ("set origin" in the tools panel)
- add a mirror modifier. Set it in Z and check "clipping"
- move the vertices you need to align (the way you want) along the Z axis
- remove the mirror modifier